# How to maintain Treeview state on postback

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net using C# 4.0. I am working on the treeview control where data is loaded from the sql database on click of the node. I am facing a issue when i redirect to some other page and come back i am not able to load the treeview with same data which i previously loaded before the page postback. can any one help on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Going to another page and coming back is not a postback.

Comment: I am navigating to other page using link.NavigateUrl which goes to the specifed page and when i come back to treeview page i need to load same data as previous.

Comment: If you are leaving the page you need to store the state in a session or in a cookie and then re-build the tree from this data in the load handler once you come back

Comment: Can you please share the code for storing the data in session and again re bilding the tree with session data.

Comment: Well, storing stuff in a session is already answered probably 1000 times here on SA, so just search a bit. You're gonna have to do a bit of thinking on the other part, though, since this is YOUR code, YOUR data model, etc, I really can't provide any useful insight

Comment: Can you provide me a related links please.

Comment: This is what you need: [Load TreeView into session](http://forums.asp.net/t/1618284.aspx/1)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link but code is not working.